# Applying FTC and Chain rule to calculate a minimum

Tags: real-analysis

Find the value of $x$ where $f(x)$ attains its minimum. (Hint: you will need the Chain Rule.)

$$f(x) = \int_{-10}^{x^2+2x} e^{t^2}\,dt. $$

I'm a little confused by this. I thought this would be calculated by finding where $f'(x)=0$ by using the fundamental theorem of calculus, but the answer is $x=-1$, where $f'(-1)$ is not $0$. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here we have to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus AND the Chain Rule: it follows that 
$$f'(x)=e^{(x^2+2x)^2}\cdot (x^2+2x)'=e^{(x^2+2x)^2}\cdot 2(x+1).$$
What is $f'(-1)$? Find where $f$ is increasing/decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let $$\int e^{t^2}dt=F(t)+C$$therefore $$f(x)=F(x^2+2x)-F(-10)$$and therefore $$f'(x)={d\over dx}F(x^2+2x)$$Now, applying Chain Rule leads to ...